# Turn off Localization in Lightswitch app

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Can I turn off Localization in my Lightswitch app so that it does not include all those bin\[culture]\*.resources.dll's in the deployment package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no you can't. This "feature" is provided by Silverlight, not LightSwitch itself, so the LS team doesn't have direct control over that.